# Invalid path to .podspec.json

Tags: cocoapods

Link to podspec looks like:
/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/["a",%20"8",%20"3",%20"myTrackerSDK",%20Pod::Version%20version=3.1.0]/myTrackerSDK.podspec.json
at [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/myTrackerSDK) repository.

Comment: Where did you get that error? How did you get that? What did you do exactly?